# Non-constructive proof that an integral obtains every value

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

> Let $C([0,1])$ be the set of continuous functions on $[0,1]$. Prove that for every $c \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists a function $f \in C([0,1])$ such that:
> $$\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx =c $$
> *Without explicitly constructing such an* $f$.

This is easy enough to do without the non-constructive condition - i.e. consider the constant function $f(a)=a$. Intuitively, the theorem is obvious, but my intuition relies on thinking up explicit curves. Without that ability, I'm just not sure what the right way to approach this problem is. I tried assuming there is no such function and deriving a contradiction, but I ended up just constructing an explicit counterexample. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What properties of the integral are you allowed to use? Because you could just say that every integral is equal to $0$, and most properties of the integral are satisfied. (And the claim would be false.)

Comment: This is a weird problem.

Comment: $I \colon f \mapsto \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-linear map $C([0,1]) \to \mathbb{R}$. Hence its image is a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}$. There are only two of those.

Comment: @zhw.: I agree. I'm almost at the point of demanding more details before downvoting or voting to close. The two current answers are fine, but could be accused of being either too explicit or too constructive. Without a clearer specification of what "without explicitly constructing $f$' means, it's a matter of opinion question, and then should be closed.

Comment: @TeaFor2: What do you mean by "without explicitly constructing"? And is this something that you're just curious about, or did it come from somewhere? If it did come from somewhere, please let us know where it was, so we can better help you to answer it.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC This was just something I was curious about, after getting a homework assignment that didn't have the "non explicit construction" condition. Saying "take $f(x)=x$" felt like a bit of a cop out so I was wondering whether there was a way to do it using properties of the map, like Daniel Fischer did above. Sorry if it's unclear - I didn't have a great idea of what I meant when I asked the question.

Comment: No worries TeaFor2. We've all had wild inchoate ideas. Next time if you add a bit of the motivation for your question people can have a better idea how to approach it. Like @DanielFisher's answer indicates, all you need to assume is linearity and just one function with a non-zero integral.

Comment: I upvoted to partially reverse the downvotes, which surprised me.  I agree that the OP didn't show **context** (i.e. in this case, what is *motivating* the problem).  I also agree that the lack of context compounded the problem of his question being bizarre and therefore hard to respond to.  **However,** the OP did show work.  I don't like the OP being downvoted because his creativity exceeded his clarity.

Comment: @user2661923: The downvote is on the question, and not on the O.P. And the vote is on the question as it currently exists. The O.P. can (and should, in my opinion) edit the question to add clarifications for future readers. In fact, as I just learned, once a couple of minutes have passed, the O.P. (or someone else) editing the question is the only way that the site will let me remove my downvote. Plus, the O.P. gets better at writing clearly for future questions!

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC rationally, your comment is a nice rebuttal to my comment.  Further, the OP, with a rating of 551, is not that new.  In general however, for new users (e.g. rating less than 100), the user will probably react negatively-emotionally to the downvote, feeling (perhaps irrationally) that the downvote is against him rather than his posting.  I also think that even with experienced users the negative-emotional reaction is triggered.  I am reluctant to downvote.  A gentler message is sent by simply commenting that the posting needs revision, otherwise it may be downvoted.

Comment: @user2661923: We clearly have different strategies for helping users become better contributors to the site.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f>0$, then let $\displaystyle g=\frac{c}{\displaystyle \int_0^1 f(x)\mathrm{d}x}f$ (well defined because $f>0$ and thus $\int_0^1f(x)\mathrm{d}x>0$). Then $\int_0^1 g(x)\mathrm{d}x=c$.

Comment: We can relax $f>0$.  Sufficient to require $\int_0^1 f \, dx \ne 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Pick any $f \in C[0,1]$ and let $c' = \int_0^1 f(x)dx$.

For any $c \in \mathbb{R}$, the function $g(x) = f(x) + (c - c')$ should have $\int_0^1 g(x)dx = c$

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)$ be a probability density function with support on $[0,1]$.

Consider $f(x)=c g(x).$

Answer (score 0):

Grab an integral (with the integrand $g(x)$ continuous of course) from zero to one at random, that evaluates to a non-zero value $\alpha$.

For example:
[Prove $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{(x-2) \sqrt[5]{x^2{(1-x)}^3}} = -\frac{2^{\frac{11}{10}} \pi}{\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5}}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3787576/prove-int-01-fracdxx-2-sqrt5x21-x3-frac2-frac1110) $=\alpha$

Let $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{c}{\alpha} g(x)$.

Comment: Okay, so maybe this $g(x)$ is *not* continuous.  Find another that is ...