# Prove $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{(x-2) \sqrt[5]{x^2{(1-x)}^3}} = -\frac{2^{11/10} \pi}{\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5}}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, special-functions

$$
\mbox{Prove}\quad
\int_{0}^{1}{\mathrm{d}x \over
\left(\,{x - 2}\,\right)\,
\sqrt[\Large 5]{\,x^{2}\,\left(\,{1 - x}\,\right)^{3}\,}\,}
=
-\,{2^{11/10}\,\pi \over \,\sqrt{\,{5 + \,\sqrt{\,{5}\,}}\,}\,}
$$

- Being honest I havent got a clue where to start.  I dont think any obvious substitutions will help ($x \to 1-x, \frac{1}{x}, \sqrt{x},$ more).
- The indefinite integral involves hypergeometric function so some miracle substitution has to work with the bounds I suspect.
- Maybe gamma function is involved some how ??.

If anyone has an idea and can provide help I would appreciate it.

Comment: I have a feeling this will be a very hot integral. I’m here before it happened.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Hint:

Substitute $x \rightarrow\frac{1}{x-1}$. We'll get: $$-\int_0^\infty \dfrac{x^{-3/5}dx}{(2x+1)}$$
Can you continue from here?

Comment: Nice!  What made you think of that substitution?

Comment: @MoQabar It results from the "obvious" substitutions that you mentioned applied multiple times.

Comment: Substituting $x \rightarrow 1/x$ will reduce integral to $$\int_1^\infty \dfrac{dx}{(1-2x)(x-1)^{3/5}}$$ Now it was obvious to substitute $x$ as $x-1$.

Comment: @Zenix  check please your integral. It looks nice by it seems to me, it is mistaken.

Comment: @user376343 My integral reduces to $-\dfrac{π}{2^{2/5} \sin(2π/5)}$, since $\sin(2π/5)=\dfrac{\sqrt{(5+√5)}}{2√2}$. Both integrals are same.

Comment: Do you did $x\mapsto1/u$ then $u\mapsto 1-x$ then multiplied by $-1$? You have more dedication than me!

Comment: @user376343 Zenix's work is correct..?  What do you think is wrong?

Comment: @Ty. With Zenix' substitution I obtain repeteadly  $\int_{-\infty}^{-1} \dfrac{dx}{(x-1)(x+1)^{2/5}}.$ With substitution $x \rightarrow\frac{1}{1-x}$ I get $-\int_1^\infty \dfrac{dx}{(x+1)(x-1)^{2/5}}.$ It is why I am asking to check the integral.

Comment: @user376343 
$$\begin{aligned}
I &= \int_2^{\infty} \frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(x-1)^2}}{\left(\frac{3-2x}{x-1}\right) \sqrt[5]{{\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right)}^2{\left(\frac{x-2}{x-1}\right)}^3 }} \\
&= \int_2^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\left(3-2x\right) {(x-2)}^{\frac{3}{5}}} \\
&\overset{x-2 \to x}= -\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{-\frac{3}{5}}}{2x+1} \mathrm{d}x \\
&\overset{2x \to x}= -2^{-\frac{2}{5}} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{-\frac{3}{5}}}{x+1} \mathrm{d}x 
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Thank you @Ty. My "problem"is rather in the logic: if I use the suggested substitution, I do not (immediately) get the integral written in the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{1}{\dd x \over \pars{x - 2}\root[\Large 5]{x^{2}\pars{1 - x}^{3}}}= -\,{2^{11/10}\,\pi \over \root{5 + \root{5}}}}:\ {\Large ?}}$.

---

\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{1}{\dd x \over \pars{x - 2}\root[\Large 5]{x^{2}\pars{1 - x}^{3}}}}
\,\,\,\stackrel{x\ \mapsto\ 1/x}{=}\,\,\,
\int_{\infty}^{1}{-\,\dd x/x^{2} \over \pars{1/x - 2}\pars{1/x}^{2/5}
\pars{1 - 1/x}^{3/5}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{1}^{\infty}{\pars{x - 1}^{-3/5} \over 1 - 2x}\,\dd x
\,\,\,\stackrel{x + 1\ \mapsto\ x}{=}\,\,\,
-\,{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{-3/5} \over x + 1/2}\,\dd x
\end{align}

---

Lets consider $\ds{\oint_{C}{z^{-3/5} \over z - 1/2}\,\dd z}$ where $\ds{C}$ is a key-hole contour which "takes care" of the principal branch of $\ds{\rule{0cm}{8mm}z^{-3/5}}$ ( with a branch-cut along
$\ds{\left(-\infty,0\right]}$ ). Namely,

\begin{align}
2\pi\ic\bracks{\pars{1 \over 2}^{-3/5}} & =
\int_{-\infty}^{0}{\pars{-x}^{-3/5}\expo{-3\pi\ic/5}
 \over x - 1/2}\,\dd x + \int_{0}^{-\infty}{\pars{-x}^{-3/5}\expo{3\pi\ic/5}
 \over x - 1/2}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
-\expo{-3\pi\ic/5}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{-3/5} \over x + 1/2}\,\dd x +
\expo{3\pi\ic/5}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{-3/5} \over x + 1/2}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
2\ic\sin\pars{3\pi \over 5}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{-3/5} \over x + 1/2}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] \implies & 
\bbox[10px,#ffd]{-\,{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{-3/5} \over x + 1/2}\,\dd x =
- 2^{3/5}\pi\csc\pars{3\pi \over 5}} \approx -2.5034
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\text { Let } x&=\sin ^2 \theta, \quad \textrm{ then } d x=2 \sin \theta \cos \theta d \theta, \textrm{ and }\\
I&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{2 \sin \theta \cos \theta d \theta}{\left(\sin ^2 \theta-2\right) \sqrt[5]{\sin ^4 \theta \cos ^6 \theta}}\\
&=2 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\tan ^{\frac{1}{5}} \theta  d \theta}{\cos ^2 \theta\left(\tan ^2 \theta-2 \sec ^2 \theta\right)}\\
&=-2 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^{\frac{1}{5}}}{t^2+2} d t ,\quad \textrm{ where }t=\tan \theta\\
&=-2\left(\frac{2^{\frac{1}{10}} \pi}{\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5}}}\right) \quad \textrm{(via beta function)} \\
&=-\frac{2^{\frac{11}{10}} \pi}{\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5}}}
\end{aligned}
$$